# Modify Controller to use/accept URL parameters in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, url-parameters

I currently have a way to take a section of data, and to send it in a new tab by itself.
[image]

The problem right now, is that this happens in the AngularJS app and the URL stays the same. So if I "open in new tab" in an Accounts item or a Customers item, the url is still the same (`app/#/apiTab`). What I would like is for the URL to change to something like `app/#/apiTab?Method=Accounts&Version=1.0` or `app/#/apiTab?Method=Customers&Version=2.3`. So that a user can copy/paste that to someone, they can plug it in, and get the same single result on their browser.

I am not sure how possible that is.

Here is my current layout.

**apiTab.html** (the bottom page above - *the new tab that is opened*)

```
<div ng-controller="apiTabController">
  <div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        {{data.uri}}
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <table class="table">
        <tr ng-repeat="method in data.methods">
          <td>{{method.name}}</td>
          <td>{{method.desc}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Snippet of my api.html** (the top page above - *showing items you can open into new tabs*)

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
<div ng-repeat="api in apiList[0].accounts">
   <div class="panel panel-info" id="panel1">
      <div class="panel-heading">
         <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseAccountsV{{$index}}" class="collapsed">
            {{api.uri}}
            </a>
            <i class="newTab" ng-click="apiTab(api)">(Open in new tab)</i>
         </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseAccountsV{{$index}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
         <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table">
               <tr ng-repeat="method in api.methods">
                  <td>{{method.name}}</td>
                  <td>{{method.desc}}</td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**apiController.js** (*Push data to sessionStorage*)

```
angular.module('app').controller('APIController', ['$scope', '$location', 'APIMethodService', function($scope, $location, APIMethodService) {
    $scope.title = "API";
    $scope.apiList = APIMethodService.apis;

    $scope.apiTab = function(apiData) {
      sessionStorage.setItem("apiData", JSON.stringify(apiData));
      window.open("#/apiTab");
    };
}]);
```

**apitabController.js** (*Pull data from sessionStorage for new tab*)

```
angular.module('app').controller('apiTabController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      var retrieved = sessionStorage.getItem("apiData");
      $scope.data = JSON.parse(retrieved);
}]);
```

**Question:** How can I setup this up to optionally receive, and display, URL parameters so that  user can use a URL to go straight to a specific API section rather than having to click it within the main api.html.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're storing that data in sessionStorage, could you:

1. Save `apiData` to sessionStorage
2. Change their $location.path
3. Check sessionStorage on `$routeChangeStart` to see if `apiData` is stored
4. If stored, retrieve `apiData` and then remove from sessionStorage

Probably not ideal...

Comment: Any advice on implementing any of that/tutorial? I am still newer to Angular